# Не работает комбинация селекторов .button:hover .input-text

Tags: html, css

Не работает комбинация селекторов:

```
.button:hover .input-text {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```
<form class="form" action="#" method="POST">
    <input class="input input-text" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Эл. почта">
    <input class="input button" type="button" name="button">
</form>
```

```
/* Form
==========================*/

.input {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;

    font-family: "PT Sans";
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.4;

    border: 1px solid #707070;
}

.input:hover {
    border: 1px solid #353535;
}

.input:focus {
    outline: none;
}


/* Button
====================*/

.button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;

    background: url("../img/icons/send-icon.svg") no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-left: none;
}

.button:hover .input-text {
    border-right: none;
}

.button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы, скорее всего, пытаетесь менять стиль у **предыдущего** элемента, который является либо родительским либо соседним, но стоящим выше в разметке. Так CSS не работает (кроме трюков  с псевдоклассом `:focus-within`).

Решения два:

- Изменение разметки с последующим позиционированием элементов в нужном порядке через CSS (например, с помощью *position* или *flex*):

  ```css
  /* Form
  ==========================*/
  .form {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

  .input {
    height: 50px; padding: 10px;
    font: 1rem/1.4 "PT Sans";
    border: 5px solid #707070;
  }
  .input:hover { border: 5px solid #353535; }
  .input:focus { outline: none; }

  /* Button
  ====================*/
  .button {
    width: 70px;
    background: url("../img/icons/send-icon.svg") no-repeat center;
    border-left: none;
  }

  .button:hover + .input-text {
    border-right: none;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <form class="form" action="#" method="POST">
    <input class="input button" type="button" name="button">
    <input class="input input-text" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Эл. почта">
  </form>
  ```
- Использовать JS и обработчики (возможно *inline-*), для доступа к нужному элементу:

  ```css
  /* Form
  ==========================*/
  .input {
    height: 50px; padding: 10px;
    font: 1rem/1.4 "PT Sans";
    border: 5px solid #707070;
  }
  .input:hover { border: 5px solid #353535; }
  .input:focus { outline: none; }

  /* Button
  ====================*/
  .button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    background: url("../img/icons/send-icon.svg") no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-left: none;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <form class="form" action="#" method="POST">
    <input class="input input-text" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Эл. почта">
    <input class="input button" onmouseover="this.previousElementSibling.style.borderRight = 'none'" onmouseout="this.previousElementSibling.style.borderRight = ''" type="button" name="button">
  </form>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`.button:hover .input-text` замените на `.input.button:hover input.input-text`
Должно сработать или же так `.button.input-text:hover`

Comment: Увы, но не работает(